# creating a random list with specified number of random values

Tags: python, list, random

Is there a **command** to create *directly* a list with length 20 that contains exactly 10's 0 and 10's 1, randomly?

My code for doing that is as follows:

```
import random

my_list = []

for i in range(20):
    if i <= 9:
        my_list.append(0)
    else:
        my_list.append(1)

random.shuffle(my_list)
```

But I wonder if there is a method to do this directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably as short as it gets.

```
lst = [0, 1]*10
random.shuffle(lst)
```